# Find $\lim_\limits{x\to \infty}{\sqrt[3]{x^3+ax^2+bx+c}-x}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Find $\lim_\limits{x\to \infty}{\sqrt[3]{x^3+ax^2+bx+c}-x}$. As I understand, I should use Taylor series, but I don't know how. What should I translate into Taylor series, to what extent, etc. This is the formula I know: $f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{f^{(j)}(x_0)\over j!}(x-x_0)^j+o((x-x_0)^n)$. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: This is more about the series than about the limit.

Comment: Does the answer using Taylor series at the linked question help you?  (Ctrl f to find "Taylor" quickly)

Comment: Actually, yes. 
For the first time I see it was fully explained.